# unexpected output with templates and non-templates functions

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Template func and non template func call order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174493/template-func-and-non-template-func-call-order)

Why does this code code print

```
::foo(int)
::foo<T>(T)
```

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T)
{
   std::cout << "::foo<T>(T) \n";
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T baz)
{
   foo(baz);
}

void foo(int)
{
   std::cout << "::foo(int) \n";
}

int main()
{
   foo(0);
   bar(0); 
}
```

while this

```
void foo(int)
{
   std::cout << "::foo(int) \n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T)
{
   std::cout << "::foo<T>(T) \n";
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T baz)
{
   foo(baz);
}

int main()
{
   foo(0);
   bar(0); 
}
```

prints

```
::foo(int)
::foo(int)
```

as expected.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174493/template-func-and-non-template-func-call-order

Comment: While I can't consider it an answer it is worth reading in the context of your question: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because a template function only considers functions visible at the point of definition, not functions visible at the point of instantiation. If it picked functions based on instantiation visibility you'd be violating the one definition rule left and right most likely. There's a standard reference in my answer to the related question [Adding specializations of template functions later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453737/adding-specializations-of-template-functions-later)

Comment: I think (not 100% on this) that if you were to put your function prototypes before any definitions that this would also solve this, even if the prototypes were in a semi-random order.  As long as they're all ahead of the definitions, I think that also works.